# How to increase Faction BPC from 1 run to 2 runs in Eve Online?

Tags: eve-online

http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Standings_mechanics

On this link faction BPC runs can be 2 if your standing is great like 8 and above.....

So who and where can I do this????

Answer (score 2):

As explained on [this](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Cosmos_faction_ship_offers) wiki page you need to grind your **Faction** (not corporation) standings up to the appropriate level; 8.5 for Frigate BPCs, 9.2 for Cruiser BPCs, and 9.9 for Battleship BPCs.

After you've got the required Faction (again not corporation) standing you can purchase 2 run BPCs from agents in COSMOS space in exchange for 30 of the appropriate type of tag, which is dependent on which BPC you want.

[This page](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/COSMOS) is a comprehensive list of COSMOS agents, their rewards, and the requirements for the rewards.